# knitr file ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim

Tags: latex, knitr, sweave, rnw

I have the following `.Rnw` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\hskip-3.5cm\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
\cellcolor[RGB]{0,0,140}{\large\textbf{\textcolor{white}{Bill To: }}}\\
\hline

\textbf{
"asdf"
}\\
\\[-1em]
\textbf{asdf@asdf.com} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\hskip6cm\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Date: & 05/31/2018 \\
\hline
Invoice \#: & 1234asdf \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

which gives me the expected pdf: [image]

However, when I replace the "asdf" with R code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\hskip-3.5cm\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
\cellcolor[RGB]{0,0,140}{\large\textbf{\textcolor{white}{Bill To: }}}\\
\hline

\textbf{
<<asdf>>=
cat("asdf")
@
}\\
\\[-1em]
\textbf{asdf@asdf.com} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\hskip6cm\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Date: & 05/31/2018 \\
\hline
Invoice \#: & 1234asdf \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim
```

Looking at the generated `.tex` file, this is the relevant part:

```
\textbf{
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{alltt}
\hlkwd{cat}\hlstd{(}\hlstr{"asdf"}\hlstd{)}
\end{alltt}
\begin{verbatim}
## asdf
\end{verbatim}
\end{kframe}
\end{knitrout}
}\\
```

and this is what the `.log` file says:

```
Runaway argument?
 #### asdf \end {verbatim} \end {kframe} \end {knitrout} \check@icr \expandafte
r \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> test2.tex

I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Emergency stop.
<*> test2.tex
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you can embed a verbatim environment in `\textbf`.  `Sweave` uses the `fancyvrb` package to let you modify the display of R output; I'm not sure if you can do the same in `knitr` or not.

Comment: Correct, you should use textbf inside the chunk instead: `<<asdf, results='asis', echo = F>>=
cat("\\textbf{asdf}")
@`

Comment: Thanks, @MartinSchmelzer's suggestion worked.

Comment: Actually, the `results='asis'` is sufficient in the original.  That will stop `knitr` from wrapping the result in `\begin{verbatim}` etc.  Alternatively you can change the wrapper by playing with `knitr::knit_opts$set(output = ...)` to change how R output is handled, but I think the `'asis'` solution is simpler and better.

Answer (score 1):

By default, R output is wrapped in a LaTeX verbatim environment, and you can't put one of those inside `\textbf`.  There are a couple of different approaches to fix this.

The simplest is just to use the chunk option `results='asis'`, i.e.

```
\textbf{
<<asdf,results='asis',echo=FALSE>>=
cat("asdf")
@
}
```

This will prevent `knitr` from adding the environment around the output; the LaTeX code will just be

```
\textbf{
asdf
}
```

which should be fine.

If you want the default formatting but just want to change the font or style of text, things are harder.  You need to tell `knitr` to use a different environment instead of `verbatim`, e.g. the `Verbatim` environment provided by the `fancyvrb` package.  You can do this by changing the output hook.  For example, this should work

```
% in the preamble:
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
<<include=FALSE>>=
oldhook <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("output")
bold <- function(x, options)
  paste0("\\begin{Verbatim}[fontseries=b]\n", x, "\\end{Verbatim}")
@

% in the body:
<<asdf,echo=FALSE>>=
knitr::knit_hooks$set(output = bold)
cat("asdf")
@
% Optionally restore the old hook...
<<include=FALSE>>=
knitr::knit_hooks$set(output = oldhook)
@
```

However, it doesn't always work, because some options (like `fontseries=b`) conflict with settings that `knitr` makes.  You can change to italic (using `fontshape=it`), but not to bold.  So stick with the first suggestion.